# npm install angularfire2 fails with error ELIFECYCLE

Tags: angular, angularfire

npm install angularfire2  fails with error ELIFECYCLE

My node version is 4.4.0 and web-driver manager is at 9.0.0

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "angularfire2" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! angularfire2@2.0.0-alpha.12 postinstall: `typings install; webdriver-manager update`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angularfire2@2.0.0-alpha.12 postinstall script 'typings install; webdriver-manager update'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angularfire2 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install; webdriver-manager update
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angularfire2
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angularfire2
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try npm install webdriver-manager, 
then install angularfire2

Comment: Already tried this but no luck. Reported this issue to angularfire2 team and hey are fixing it in next release. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/100